# Mat explicit assignment error opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I am trying to initialize a Mat variable, that will hold the following matrix

```
    [1,0,0,0
     0,1,0,0
     0,0,1,0
     0,0,0,1]
```

From this [link](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html), I got a method to do this and implemented the same

```
    Mat Tfrm = (Mat_double(4,4)<<1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1);
```

However, I faced the following error

```
    resectioning_1.cpp:809:28: error: ‘Mat_double’ was not declared in this scope
```

Can you please tell me how to resolve this? I googled but got nowhere. Maybe am not sure of what to search. I knowthis is a simple issue, but pelase help me. If there's another simple way to achieve what am trying to do, please let me know. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `Mat_<double>` instead of `Mat_double`:

```
Mat Tfrm = (Mat_<double>(4,4)<<1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1);
```